# Microsoft stack web host with HIPAA expertise?

Tags: .net, iis, web-hosting, hipaa

I'm a consultant, helping a provider of small medical practice management software move to the web. We're looking for a host that has experience with HIPAA-compliance, and supports the MS Web stack (IIS/.NET/SQL Server)

Can anyone here provide a recommendation of such a hosting company?

Comment: This question might do better on serverfault.com

Answer (score 0):

Look at [Connectria](http://www.connectria.com/windows_hosting.asp); they seem to meet all of your requirements and have a quite impressive client list.  I haven't used them personally though.